# Circuitikz - aligning nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, coordinates

I was drawing circuit in tikz and find problem.

First problem: I am not able to align verticaly open nodes on the left. Is there simple solution for that?

Second problem: Is there way to get for example Y coordinate of T.A1 and put it into another coordinate? Example: \draw (0,T.A1) -- (3,T.A1);
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}%[european]
  \ctikzset{transformer L2/.style={inductors/coils=8,inductors/width=1.2}}
  % \ctikzset{quadpoles/transformer/width=1, quadpoles/transformer/height=6}
  \ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width=.1}
  \draw (0,0) to [short,o-] (0.5,0) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm,R=$R_z$] (2.5,0) node[transformer core, anchor=A1](T){};
  \draw (T.B1) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm,R=$R_t$] (6.5,0) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm,C=$C_1$] (8,0) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm,D*=$P_1$] (10,0) to [short,-o] (11,0) node[anchor=south west] {A};
  \draw (8,-2) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm,D*=$P_2$] (8,0);
  \draw (10,-2) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=1cm,C=$C_2$] (10,0);
  \draw (6.5,0) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.75cm,C=$C'_d$] (6.5,-1) to [/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=.75cm,C=$C''_d$] (6.5,-2);
  \draw (T.B2) to [-] ($(T.B2)+(2,0)$) -| (6.5,-2);
  \draw (T.B2) to [-] ($(T.B2)+(2,0)$) -| (8,-2);
  \draw (T.B2) to [-] ($(T.B2)+(2,0)$) -| (10,-2);
  \draw (10,-2) node[ground](GND){};
  % \draw (and_2.in 2) to[short, -o] ++ (-60pt, 0) coordinate(x3) node[left]{$x_3$};
  \draw (T.A2) to [short,-o] ++(-60pt,0) coordinate(x3);% -| (0,-2);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As for your second question: `\draw (0,0 |- T.A1) -- (3,0 |- T.A1);` should do. As for your first question: replace the (second to) last line with `\draw (T.A2) to[short,-o] (T.A2 -| 0,0) coordinate (x3);` to align the two coordinates.

Comment: A short explanation `(A |- B)` means: Take the *x* part of the coordinate of `A` and the *y* coordinate of `B`. You can also use `-|`. To make sense of this syntax, I usually think of the two strokes as markers on a horizontal or vertical ruler. So `|` would mark some value in the horizontal dimension and therefore `A |` in `(A |- B)` means: take the *x* part of `A` (since the *x* axis is horizontal). Not sure whether this makes any sense to you, though ... =D

Comment: @JasperHabicht I find more intuitive to think at `(A |- B)` as: start from `A`; go vertically (`|`) ; start from `B`, go horizontally (`-`) — the coordinate is the crosspoint. (well, basically what you said, thinking twice...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a syntax that allows you to select a coordinate that takes the *x* value of another coordinate and the *y* value of yet another coordinate. The syntax is `(A |- B)` meaning at the *x* value of the coordinate of `A` and the *y* value of the coordinate of `B`. There is also `(A -| B)` which would then use the *x* value of the coordinate of `B`.

So, based on this, I'd probably do the following:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{
    transformer L2/.style={
        inductors/coils=8, 
        inductors/width=1.2,
    },
    quadpoles/transformer core/height=2.5,
    bipoles/capacitor/width=.1,
    bipoles/length=1cm,
    /tikz/short bipole/.style={
        /tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=.75cm,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}

  \draw (0,0) to [short, o-] (0.5,0) 
    to[R=$R_z$] (2.5,0) 
    node[transformer core, anchor=A1] (T) {};
  \draw (T.A2) 
    to[short, -o] (T.A2 -| 0,0);
  
  \draw (T.B1) 
    to[R=$R_t$] (6.5,0) 
    to[C=$C_1$] (8,0) 
    to[D*=$P_1$] (10,0) 
    to[short, -o] (11,0) node[anchor=south west] {A};
  \draw (8,0 |- T.A2) 
    to[D*=$P_2$] (8,0);
  \draw (10,0 |- T.A2) 
    node[ground] (GND) {}
    to[C=$C_2$] (10,0);
  \draw (6.5,0) 
    to[short bipole, C=$C'_d$] (6.5,0 |- T.center) 
    to[short bipole, C=$C''_d$] (6.5,0 |- T.A2);
  \draw (T.B2) to (GND.center);
 
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]